# OSGI classes not visible even though the required JARs are in Bundle-classpath

Tags: spring, persistence, osgi, equinox

We are using an Equinox based OSGI framework to run Multiple bundles.
Our bundles have dependent JARs in the Bundle-classpath and the dependent JARs are packaged along with the rest of the classes and resources in a single JAR/WAR file.
But we have a problem while running multiple such Bundles.
Say,
Bundle A: Fully tested/working JAR bundle. Contains all dependent JARs in the bundle classpath and all the dependent JARs inside (under a folder named lib). Working fine when tested by deploying only this bundle

Bundle B: Similar to Bundle A. Again working when deploying separately

But when both bundles are loaded together, OSGI is not able to load classes from JARs mentioned in the bundle-classpath for the bundle that is loaded second. The bundle that is loaded first runs fine, whereas the bundle loaded second fails.

This issue currently occurs while SPRING tries to load `javax.persistence.QueryHint` class.

We create a Data source using our xxxx-EntityManager.xml where we create our `entityManagerFactory`

Dependent JARs used: (Same JARs in both the bundles)

- Spring: 3.0.6.RELEASE JARS
- Hibernate: 3.6.7 JARS
- Hibernate-JPA: hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

Exception:
`PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'targetDataSources' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [xxxx-EntityManager.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.persistence.QueryHint is not visible from class loader
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)`

Note:

- Both the Bundles have been individually tested and working fine
- We know that, instead of creating Bundle-classpath we can extract the thirdparty JARs outside of the bundles and use import-package. But for this current requirement, we need the third party JARs inside the parent bundle only.

Requesting OSGI experts to please help us out.

Comment: I think the answers below have jumped the gun, we need more information first. It *should* be possible to create both bundles so they are entirely isolated and work separately. I'd like to know where the `javax.persistence` package is being loaded from in the *working* bundle.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to put your dependencies in individual bundles and make all packages visible to other bundles. Then add these individual bundles as dependencies (or better: import only the required packages instead of the whole bundle!). This way you can ensure that your dependencies are loaded just once. I suggest that your current configuration leads to problems in class loading, as classes are loaded twice with most probably the same `serialVersionUID`. And since each bundle has its own classloader, the secondary (not) loaded class won't be visible to the second bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, we also have a plan to do this. But as per our requirements we are to deliver large self-sufficient bundles (using bundle-classpath) for this release and work on finer bundles (using import-package) for the upcoming ones. It will be helpful if we can make the bundles A and B work as they are today..

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way around if the solution @Tassos Bassoukos suggested does not fit either. It is anyway not recommended to use the classpath in OSGi environment. And I'm pretty sure that there are already OSGi bundled versions of the JARs you use, so this step is quite small. Additionally, the concept of OSGi is exactly the opposite of large deliverables.

Comment: I disagree, it *should* be possible to create both bundles so that they encapsulate all required functionality and can be used independently (though I agree it is less than optimal). Something else is going on here, which we need to get to the bottom of.

Comment: I took the OSGI compliant version (bundle) of "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar" and installed in the OSGI VM. Then I modified my bundles "A" and "B" to import the javax.persistence.* packages.. By doing so the earlier Class visibility exception was resolved. But we have a new exception.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory interface [interface org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory] seems to conflict with Spring's EntityManagerFactoryInfo mixin - consider resetting the 'entityManagerFactoryInterface' property to plain [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]

Comment: We use this bean definition with a bunch of parameters to create the Datasource
"<bean id="DirectoryEntityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">"

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory interface [interface org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory] seems to conflict with Spring's EntityManagerFactoryInfo mixin - i am getting the same exception, any luck solving it..??

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot package the JARs as separate bundles, designate eithe A or B to contain all JARs, export all packages, and make the other bundle depend on it (and remove the JARs from the second bundle).

Comment: This may not work for us. We have a requirement where each of these bundles A/B should work both independently and together in the same OSGI VM. So, we cannot exclude the libs from any one of the bundles and just depend on the import-package.

Comment: Then you're up the proverbial creek without a paddle, since the local bundle classpath will have precedence over imports; since you will have two sets of the same classes, you will have the same class loaded in two class loaders, and these classes will not be compatible with each other.